# Question regarding instructions installing OpenStack

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

The instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack list creating an account at http://www.maas.ip/MAAS
This URL does not resolve and whois shows this as an invalid domain.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it means you have to go to a website named `maas.ip`, but rather that you have to go to `http://ww.xx.yy.zz` where `ww.xx.yy.zz` is the IP address of the MAAS server.